# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s), structs

Tags: c, valgrind

I have an array of pointers to structs that I am trying to while loop with. I am not totally confident on how to exactly intialize it but I have been doing it like this:

```
Entry *newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Entry));
```

I have another function which is test code which goes through the array if the spot at the array has a filled value or null

```
Entry* current = hashTable->table[val];

    while(current != NULL){
```

I just use the Entry *current as basically a temporary variable to reference whatever was stored in the array. When doing that I get a valgrind error:
 Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Do I have to intialize that somehow? All I am trying to do is store reference to what is at that point in the array.. which may or may not be null and execute a while loop if it is not NULL

Is their a way I should initialize?

**EDIT-**
I have an array of pointers of each of these Entry structs which I initalize using this code. Which I am hoping is the correct way to do so.

```
Entry** arrayOfPointers;
    arrayOfPointers = malloc(arraySize* sizeof(Entry*));
```

**EDIT2-**
Aplogies if above wasn't minimal as I thought. Heres a minimal example

```
//create arry of pointers
        Entry** arrayOfPointers;
        arrayOfPointers = malloc(arraySize* sizeof(Entry*));

//create elements at certain indexs in array
        Entry *newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Entry));
        arrayOfPointers[1] = newEntry;
//this is the gist of what this does

//Search and do something when found something in array
//since the array is pretty big, theres going to be indexes when theres nothing
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
  //temp holder
  Entry *temp = arrayOfPointers[i];
  if(temp != NULL){
   //Do Stuff
   //This if statement is where the conditional jump or move error will be thrown
//not exactly sure what but somehow do not initialize temp correctly
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that produces the same valgrind error? There is far too much that isn't conveyed in the three lines you posted, which can lead to that.

Comment: It's not minimal. Far less so. We can't just copy it to a text file, compile, run Valgrind and see the same error.

Comment: We are not a tutoring site. Please read a C book if you want to learn the language. This site requires **one specific** problem per question. Did you ever read [ask]?

Comment: @StoryTeller Accidenlty saved it while I was editing.. just updated with a minimal example

Comment: "... since the array is pretty big, theres going to be indexes when theres nothing..." - there is ? What does "nothing" *mean* ? You know `malloc` doesn't zero-fill memory, *right* ? If you want that use `calloc`. There, that's my wild-guess. Can't be sure since there is no [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Sadly, zero-filling memory is no guarantee to get pointers that compare equal to a NULL pointer constant http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note296

Answer (score 0):

**malloc** can fail.  Hence you need to test it.

```
Entry *newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Entry));
if (newEntry != NULL)
{
    /* Use it */
    free(newEntry);
}
else
{
    printf("error - malloc failed\n");
}
```

That code allocates space for exactly one **Entry**.
I suspect you intend it to be an array

```
int elementCount = 1000;
Entry *newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Entry) * elementCount);
```

Once you have your array of dynamically allocated **Entry**, you need to initialize the values in the array

```
for (int z=0; z < elementCount; z++)
{
    newEntry[z] = {whatever value is needed to do the initialization};
}
```

Then you can start hashing and returning the address of the hashed element, and doing something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your MCVE-ish code snippet actually goes a long way towards explaining why you get this error. Let's assume `arraySize` is 3. And let's draw what your programs memory layout looks like, assuming all the calls succeed:

```
Entry** arrayOfPointers = malloc(arraySize* sizeof(Entry*));
```

With that, we get the following:

```
arrayOfPointers ------+
                      ↓
                  +-------+
                  |???????|
                  +-------+
                  |???????|
                  +-------+
                  |???????|
                  +-------+
```

Then you initialize the second entry with this:

```
Entry *newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Entry));
arrayOfPointers[1] = newEntry;
```

So you get the following:

```
arrayOfPointers ------+
                      ↓
                  +-------+
                  |???????|
                  +-------+      +-------+
                  |       |----->|       |
                  +-------+      +-------+
                  |???????|          ^
                  +-------+          |
                                     |
newEntry ----------------------------+
```

So you can imagine that when you iterate over all the pointers in the block pointed to by `arrayOfPointers`, with the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
  Entry *temp = arrayOfPointers[i];
  if(temp != NULL){
  }
}
```

You copy a bunch of indeterminate addresses (marked above with `???????`), into `temp` and proceed to compare it with `NULL`.

Valgrind is right to complain. You didn't write NULL into those pointers. They are uninitialized, and you treat them like they are. You must begin by iterating over the memory that `arrayOfPointers` points at, and initializing it:

```
Entry** arrayOfPointers = malloc(sizeof(*arrayOfPointers) * arraySize);
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
  arrayOfPointers[i] = NULL;
}
```